# RepoDB: How to query columns by different property name?

Tags: mapping, repodb

In order to map our horrible database structure to poco classes we use the fluent mapper like so:

```
FluentMapper.Entity<Article>().Table("data.Articles").Column(e => e.Id, "[Item-No]");
```

When querying the table for specific fields only, we have to use the db column name so we can use PropertyMapper to resolve the db column name from the property name:

```
var dbFieldName = PropertyMapper.Get<Article>(x => x.Id);
```

Unfortunately this throws an exception for not mapped fields (and 95 % of the fields don't need to be mapped). Is there a solution for that? Catching exceptions for 95 % of the columns would harm RepoDB's performance quite a bit. :D

Answer (score 0):

I found it, we can use PropertyMappedNameCache instead:

```
var dbFieldName = PropertyMappedNameCache.Get<Article>(x => x.Id);
```

This will return the mapped db column name or the property name if there is no mapping for it, so my helper method for fields now looks like:

```
private List<Field> GetFields(List<string> fieldNames) =>
  fieldNames.Select(x => new Field(PropertyMappedNameCache.Get<TEntity>(x))).ToList();
```